# How to Resolve Type SendBirdException Error?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, sendbird

I am implementing SendBird Messaging SDk in my xamarin android project and I want to get Channel by ChannelUrl. I have written the following code but I am getting error

[image]

How to resolve this error ?

Comment: Please do not post error messages as images, add the formatted error directly your question.

Comment: send bird xamarin sdk link please

Comment: @G.hakim I have already linked SendBird Sdk and SendBird.Droid both, Thats why it showing conflict between SendBird and SendBird.Droid